# supervisord Error: Invalid user name

Tags: supervisord

I am trying to configure `supervisord` with `golang web app` according to the [article](https://elithrar.github.io/article/running-go-applications-in-the-background/). But got an error when I run command `sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`:

```
Error: Invalid username deploy user # the user your app should run as (i.e. *not* root!)
```

I created user `deployuser` and added it to group `supervisor`

```
sudo adduser deployser supervisor
```

Supervisord config file is

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0770                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)
chown=root:supervisor            ; add our group
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

I added user `deployuser` to my app config file:

```
[program:myGolangApp]
command=/root/path/to/my/go/lang/app/myGolangApp # the location of your app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=10
user=deployuser # the user your app should run as (i.e. *not* root!)
directory=/root/path/to/my/go/lang/app/ # where your application runs from
environment=APP_SETTINGS="/srv/www/yourapp.com/prod.toml" # environmental variables
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/myGolangApp.log # the name of the log file.
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
```

My os is ubuntu server. And I am doing all the configuration logined as root.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing the comment style in the second comment ( # -> ; )to match the first style.  I can't find it in the docs, but they don't seem to use "#" for a comment.

It seems really suspicious that the entire configuration line is in the error.  If it had parsed correctly, it would just contain an error value, not the comment.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you made a typo: `deployser` vs. `deployuser`